# mongoose validation error occurs even though required field is given

Tags: javascript, mongodb, function, mongoose

```
    // Assign unique krypter id
    assignKrypterID = () => 
    {
      let id = Math.floor(Math.random()*(999999-100000)+100000);
      console.log(id);
      Krypter
        .findOne({krypter_id: id.toString()})
        .then(krypter => {
          if (krypter)
            assignKrypterID()
          else
            return id.toString()
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    const newKrypter = new Krypter({
      handle: req.body.handle,
      password: req.body.password, // plain text
      krypter_id: assignKrypterID()
    });

    // Hashes the plaintext password and saves it
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newKrypter.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        newKrypter.password = hash; // encrypted password
        newKrypter
          .save()
          .then(krypter => res.json(krypter))
          .catch(err => console.log(err));
      })
    });
```

I tried to assign a unique 6 digit id to each user during registration using the function 'assignKrypterID()'. But the following error is obtained:

[image: Obtained error]

This is my schema:

```
const KrypterSchema = new Schema({
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }, 
  krypter_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
});
```

Can't this be achieved using recursion? Or is recursion a bad move here?

Help me how to modify this to find whether the randomly generated Id is alrady assigned to an object.

Comment: Quick note: it's better to copy paste text rather than post a screenshot.
(Accessibility, search engines, convenient copy/paste...)

Comment: `assignKrypterID()` function is not returning anything . i guess function implementation is wrong, you should not recursively query mongodb, this quite heavy, instead you should find all ids at once and perform search in array of ids.
Also its better to use async/await instead of thenable promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
assignKrypterID = async() => {
  try {
    let krypter_ids = await Krypter.find({}).map(obj => obj.krypter_id)
    let flag = true
    while (flag) {
      let id = Math.floor(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000);
      console.log(id);
      if (krypter_ids.includes(id)) {
        continue;
      } else {
        flag = false
        return id.toString()
      }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    throw err
    console.log(err)
  }
}
async function foo() {
  try {
    let krypter_id = (await assignKrypterID()) || ""
    const newKrypter = new Krypter({
      handle: req.body.handle,
      password: req.body.password, // plain text
      krypter_id: krypter_id
    });

    // Hashes the plaintext password and saves it
    let salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10)
    let hash = await bcrypt.hash(newKrypter.password, salt)
    newKrypter.password = hash; // encrypted password
    let krypter = await newKrypter.save()
    res.json(krypter)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    throw err
  }

}

foo()
```